# Index Val List VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have a Listbox called ListTxtDrawR4. Every time I select an item, I want to display the value corresponding to the index in a textbox with name TxtNumberListScan.Lines(i). for example, if I select the 5th line in ListTxtDrawR4, I want to display the value of line 5 from TxtNumberListScan in another Textbox. how do I do that?

```
 TxtTop10HighestResult.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtNumberListScan.Lines(TxtTop10HighestCount.Lines(0))
        TxtTop10HighestResult.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtNumberListScan.Lines(TxtTop10HighestCount.Lines(1))
        TxtTop10HighestResult.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtNumberListScan.Lines(TxtTop10HighestCount.Lines(2))
        TxtTop10HighestResult.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtNumberListScan.Lines(TxtTop10HighestCount.Lines(3))
        TxtTop10HighestResult.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtNumberListScan.Lines(TxtTop10HighestCount.Lines(4))
        TxtTop10HighestResult.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtNumberListScan.Lines(TxtTop10HighestCount.Lines(5))
```

Comment: You mean something like `"TxtNumberListScan.Lines(" & ListTxtDrawR4.SelectedIndex.ToString & ")"` ??

Comment: Yes, charles may.

Comment: Yea, @Mary, it was a question on if the OP was wanting to build that string by concatenating the SelectedIndex. Not meant to be a working piece of code.

Comment: @CharlesMay  Got it. :-) Deleting my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names of controls have been changed to protect the innocent. (I watch Dragnet :-)

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'This is just some data to test with
    Dim A() As String = {"Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"}
    Dim B() As String = {"Peter", "Paul", "James", "Judas"}
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(A)
    For Each s In B
        TextBox1.Text &= s & Environment.NewLine
    Next
    TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd() 'Remove final new line
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim index As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
    'Check that the index does not exceed the number of lines.
    If index < TextBox1.Lines.Count Then
        Dim StringToCopy = TextBox1.Lines(index)
        TextBox2.Text &= StringToCopy & Environment.NewLine
    End If
End Sub
```